# How to add ASCII char to regex validation annotation?

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, validation

I want to validate textbox is it only text. But I need some special chars for Eastern Europe such as

> **č,ć,š,đ,Č,Ć,Š,Đ,ž,Ž** (ASCII is for e.g: & #269;)

I have this validation which is just fine but it not supports my special chars:

```
 [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters only please")]
```

I've tried to add like this but I failed:

```
 [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$&#269", ErrorMessage = "Use letters only please")]
```

If you know way around I would appreciate it.

Comment: Why put them outside the character class? Use `[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z\u010D]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters only please")]` or use literals: ``[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-ZčćšđČĆŠĐžŽ]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters only please")]``

Comment: Thanks! It didnt across on my mind.

Comment: Will you delete the question or shall I post an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put them **inside the character class**.

Use something like (and add hex values with `\u` notation):

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z\u010D]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters only please")]
```

or use literals (easier and more maintainable):

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-ZčćšđČĆŠĐžŽ]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters only please")]
```